# Facebook login works in Safari but not in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, uiwebview

I have a an app with a `UIWebView` that displays a [web page](http://kode.co.nf/iOS/Facebook_JS/login.php) which has Facebook login. I'm using Facebook's JavaScript SDK (I cannot use the iOS SDK).

The login works perfectly when I open the site in mobile Safari but not in the web view. The login dialog opens, I enter the user credentials and it redirects to a blank white page. I know what causes this. Ina  normal browser, this login dialog opens in a new window. But since `UIWebView` does not support multiple windows, the login replaces the webpage and once it is successfully logged in, it can't redirect back to the original web page.

I've searched all over SO for solutions but almost all of them are outdated. I don't think there is a straight forward fix for this but if anyone has a workaround/hack, please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: @rAzOr I actually couldn't find a solution to this. Sorry.

Comment: Isuru, I know it's been a while, but did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @byron I don't think I found a solution. Honestly I don't remember since this was so long ago and I don't have access to this project now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added Facebook application ID  (your app id) into Xcode project - app's url schema. Then make sure to redirect user back to your page after fb login.

```
      - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
            {

            NSString *url = [[webView.request URL] absoluteString];

          //  if([url hasPrefix:@"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"])
 if([url hasPrefix:@"https://m.facebook.com/home.php?"])

            {
            /* here you must implement method to send user to your page */
                [self backToMyPage]; 
            }
           }

           }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I tried this method and it works but only under certain circumstances. As in, this works if I use the original login button provided by Facebook. If I use a custom button for fb login, this method doesn't work. Have you come across this scenario?